# Dynamic Layout issue adding padding in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a `LinearLayout` object and want to dynamically change the background image with a dynamically adding image object (it changes its color dynamically).

here is the code :

```
            if (categoryResponse != null && categoryResponse.result != null
                    && categoryResponse.result.length > 0) {

                int i = 0;
                category = new TextView[categoryResponse.result.length];
                for (Category cat : categoryResponse.result) {

                    category[i] = new TextView(getActivity());
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    par.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
                    category[i].setLayoutParams(par);

                    category[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    category[i].setText(cat.name);
                    category[i].setTag(cat.id);

                    category[i].setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
                    category[i].setTextSize(25);
                    category[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.category);
                    category[i].setTypeface(Global.AppsFont);
                    category[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.white));


                    main.addView(category[i]);

                    //System.out.println("header textview width = " +category[i].getWidth() + "");

                    category[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String id = (String) v.getTag();

                            for (Entry<String, LinearLayout> entry : channels
                                    .entrySet()) {

                                if (entry.getKey().equals(id)) {
                                    entry.getValue().setVisibility(
                                            View.VISIBLE);
                                } else
                                    entry.getValue().setVisibility(
                                            View.GONE);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    i++;

                    LinearLayout LLM = null;
                    LLM = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

                    channels.put(cat.id, LLM);

                    LLM.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    LLM.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams LLParamsm = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                    LLParamsm.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    LLM.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    LLM.setLayoutParams(LLParamsm);

                    LLM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.category_bg);


                    main.addView(LLM);
                    LinearLayout LL = null;

                    int j = 0;
                    ChannelResponse channelResponse = JsonUtils
                            .getChannel(cat.id);

                    channelResponseData.put(cat.id, channelResponse);
                    if (channelResponse != null
                            && channelResponse.result != null
                            && channelResponse.result.length > 0) {

                        for (Channel chan : channelResponse.result) {

                            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                                LL = new LinearLayout(getActivity());


                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams LLParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                                LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                                LL.setWeightSum(1);

                                LL.setLayoutParams(LLParams);
                                LLM.addView(LL);                                    
                            }

                            Button chn = new Button(getActivity());
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams ladderFLParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.5f);
                            ladderFLParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                            chn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_selector);
                            chn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            chn.setLayoutParams(ladderFLParams);
                            chn.setText(chan.name);
                            chn.setTag(chan.id);
                            chn.setTextSize(25);
                            chn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                                    R.color.black));
                            chn.setTypeface(Global.AppsFont);
                            chn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    channelIdid = (String) v.getTag();
                                    createDialogBox(v);
                                }

                            });

                            LL.addView(chn);
                            channel.add(chn);

                            j++;
                        }

                        if (j % 2 != 0) {

                            Button chn = new Button(getActivity());
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams ladderFLParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);
                            ladderFLParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

                            chn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_selector);
                            chn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
                                    | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                            chn.setLayoutParams(ladderFLParams);
                            chn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            chn.setTextSize(25);
                            chn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                                    R.color.black));
                            chn.setTypeface(Global.AppsFont);

                            LL.addView(chn);
                            channel.add(chn);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }'
```

Comment: problem in LLM object of Linear layout. when i am adding image auto adding padding, i have try also other image for background... image is nine patch

Comment: problem solve thank http://stackoverflow.com/users/2088815/bruce

Answer (score 0):

9-patch images automatically add the padding that is built into the 9-patch, as padding to the view. Thus when you call `LLM.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)` that is being overridden when you call `LLM.setBackgroundResource`.

Here is the doc about 9-patches: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

If you don't want padding, your best option would be to design your 9-patch without padding, in other words with both the drawable and stretchable areas going to the edge of the image.

I suppose you could also try calling setPadding after setBackgroundResource, but I'm not sure if that would work. Really you should just design your background with your desired padding in mind.

Does that make sense?